# Linux distribution for a netbook with 7-inch display with 800×480 screen resolution

Tags: linux, software-rec, small-distribution, netboot

What distros work well on an eeePC with an 800x480 7-inch non-touch display and a 2GB SSD flash drive? I tried a couple, but they're definitely not optimized for 800x480. I need something for rich text editing, for video, and for web browsing.

Answer (score 1):

I use Archlinux on mine.  It's worked well for me for nearly four years now.

Answer (score 0):

[Ångström](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) is probably your best bet; it's made for embedded devices, which frequently have smaller screens.